# NULL AS OUT in SELECT statements

Tags: sql-server, select, syntax

I am trying to solve this exercise:

Under the assumption that receipts of money (inc) and payouts (out) can be registered any number of times a day for each collection point [i.e. the code column is the primary key], display a table with one corresponding row for each operating date of each collection point.
Result set: point, date, total payout per day (out), total money intake per day (inc).
Missing values are considered to be NULL.

After several hours of headbanging I found this solution online:

```
SELECT X.POINT,X.DATE,SUM(OUT),SUM(INC) FROM (
    SELECT I.POINT,I.DATE,NULL AS OUT, SUM(I.INC) AS INC FROM INCOME I
    GROUP BY I.POINT,I.DATE
    UNION 
    SELECT O.POINT,O.DATE,SUM(O.OUT) AS OUT , NULL AS INC FROM OUTCOME O
    GROUP BY O.POINT,O.DATE) AS X
GROUP BY POINT,DATE
```

I tried to understand how this works. I googled all variations of "NULL AS OUT" but I could not find any explanation/concept. All results point out to stored procedures which is not what I am looking fro I think.

Can someone explain to me how these lines with "AS OUT" work, please?

```
SELECT I.POINT,I.DATE,NULL AS OUT, SUM(I.INC) AS INC FROM INCOME I
GROUP BY I.POINT,I.DATE
UNION 
SELECT O.POINT,O.DATE,SUM(O.OUT) AS OUT , NULL AS INC FROM OUTCOME O
```

[On the left - The complete version of both tables
On the right the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxSnC.png)

Comment: is this SQL server or mysql. from my understanding I think `as out` means `null` is referred to a column named OUT, basically alias name for a column. Income table will not have outcome and outcome table will not have income. Hence in both the select statement, the respective values are marked as null (`NULL AS OUT` & `NULL AS INC`). when you perform aggregate on these column then you null values will be ignored.

Comment: This is SQL Server I belive. The exercise is from sql-ex.ru

Comment: I understand what NULL as out and Null as inc accomplish in this querie. What I dont understand is how is this concept called and how can I use it in future projects

Comment: to start with try using alias names in simple select statement, like `select getdate() as cur_date`. Also you can use `NULL as <column name>` when your come across a similar union statement where one of the two tables does not have a column. In that case you can create this missing column as a dummy one and use it in your code.

Comment: I think this is enough. Thank you! How do I mark this answer as helpful?

Comment: comments cannot be marked as answers, I can post it as answer and you can mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying comment as answer to mark it as worked

> 

is this SQL server or mysql. from my understanding I think as out means null is referred to a column named OUT, basically alias name for a column. Income table will not have outcome and outcome table will not have income. Hence in both the select statement, the respective values are marked as null (NULL AS OUT & NULL AS INC). when you perform aggregate on these columns then the null values will be ignored.

you can use NULL as  when your come across a similar union statement where one of the two tables does not have a column. In that case you can create this missing column as a dummy one and use it in your code.

Answer (score 1):

`out` is probably an unfortunate name there, but other than that, there's nothing magical there.
"null" is the literal value of `null`.
"as out" assigns a column alias to the selected `null`.

Syntactically, this is the equivalent to any other literal value with any other alias, e.g., `SELECT 'some_varchar_literal' AS some_alias` or `SELECT 123 AS numeric_alias`.

Comment: Thank you Mreinik. This was helpfull. I am new. Love the community here